# Develop Entity Framework class that will define a .mdf database

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-express

I am trying to develop Entity Framework class that will define a .mdf database already created and filled leading up to actually creating one and filling it.

Error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> testclass.test: : EntityType 'test' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   testData: EntityType: EntitySet 'testData' is based on type 'test' that has no keys defined.

Code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace testclass
{
public class test
{
    public int idt { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<test> testData { get; set; }
}
public class testRepository
{
    public List<test> Gettest()
    {
        TestDbContext testDbContext = new TestDbContext();
        return testDbContext.testData.ToList();
    }
}
}
```

connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="TestDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=C:\folders\testclass\testclass\App_Data\Data.mdf;User Instance=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some issues with your code:

- the main is the lack of a **primary key** on your entity: EF can infer some keys if their names match some **conventions** : "**Id**", "**ID**", "**testId**"... So either use one of these standard names or explicitly mark your property as a primary key with the `[Key]` attribute:

  ```
  [Key]
  public int idt { get; set; }
  ```
- to ensure proper cleanup of the resources allocated by the `DbContext` you should wrap its usage in a `using` block:

  ```
  using (TestDbContext testDbContext = new TestDbContext())
  {
       return testDbContext.testData.ToList();
  }
  ```
- in .Net the **naming conventions** are: **CamelCase** for everything except local variables and fields; so `testclass` should be `Testclass`, `col1` should be `Col1`, `testData` should be `TestData`...